# How to remove columns in JQuery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I want to remove the columns which have total = 0.

So I've tried in different ways.

First, I assigned ID to all columns, for example; every `<td>` is of column will have their ID eg: First columns `<td ID = 'col_1'>` , second column all `<td ID = 'col_2'>` etc. And then in when footer callback I've tried to remove if this column total is ZERO then this `$("col_"+i).remove()`; this code removed table headers only so I've tried again with **$("col_"+i).empty()**  but again it's just empty. `<th>` only

Then I've tried to hide the columns by creating dynamic but I don't get any values.

```
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) 
    {
        var api = this.api(), data;  
        var intVal = function ( i ) { return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 : typeof i === 'number' ?    i : 0;};

        var col_gonna_invis = '[';
        for(i=1;i<length_of_coloumns;i++)
            {
                total_salary = api.column( i ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {return intVal(a) + intVal(b);},0 );
                $('#total_cont_'+i).html(total_salary); 
                if(total_salary == 0)
                {
                    col_gonna_invis += '{"targets": [ '+i+' ], "visible": false, "searchable": false },';
                }
            }
        col_gonna_invis += ']';alert(col_gonna_invis);  
    },

    "aoColumnDefs": col_gonna_invis;
```

Please someone help me fix this issue or please someone tell me how to hide or remove columns which footer total is 0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a fiddle?  It'd be easier to help that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest you use the [**`visible()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible()) API method along with the [**`sum()`**](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()) plugin :

Enhance the API with a `column().sum()` method :

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function ( ) {
    return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
        if ( typeof a === 'string' ) {
            a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
        }
        if ( typeof b === 'string' ) {
            b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
        }

        return a + b;
    }, 0 );
} );
```

now, in `initComplete()` you can very easy hide columns which have a `total` or `sum()` of 0 :

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
   //... 
   initComplete : function() {
      var api = this.api(), 
          colCount = api.row(0).data().length;
      for (var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
          if (api.column(i).data().sum() == 0) {
              api.column(i).visible(false);
          }
      }     
    }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qer7e5os/**

Comment: @davidkonard simply awesome.. Thank you lot :) once again thank you